# BSS segment in c, way of progress

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, assembly

I'm new in c programing and im trying to better understand where variables are saved in regarding to the memory layout of a C program.

i got the following code:

```
int addr5;              
int addr6;

/*code continues*/

int main (int argc, char** argv){

    printf("- &addr5: %p\n",&addr5);        
    printf("- &addr6: %p\n",&addr6);

/*code continues*/
```

now, when i run this code, i get that:

- &addr5: 0x804a034
- &addr6: 0x804a030

now, from what i have read, i got that the heap memory starts from lower values (and grows as we go on)
and that the stack memory starts from high values (and dec as we go on).

since i saved addr5 and addr6 as uninitialized  var, and outside of a function scoop, aren't they supposed to be saved in the BSS segment? 
and if so, isnt bss segment grows as we go, since its in the heap?

shouldn't addr6 be bigger than addrs5 as it was initialized later?

thank you.

Comment: You also need to be aware that a compiler/linker doesn't need to lay out the variables in the same order you have defined them, (Though for struct or union members, it have to).

Comment: thank you, it makes things clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `.bss` segment is not in the heap. The `.bss` segment and the `.data` segment are fixed-size segments that are typically close to the heap in address space, but they are clearly distinct from the heap.

No, the `.bss` segment does not grow. The number of global variables you define in your program stays constant during the program execution. If you load a dynamic library, then that dynamic library will have its own `.bss` segment that is placed to another location in the address space.

Comment: ok i understand what you are saying, but does the heap and stack does grow/get-smaller as they go?

Comment: and tnx for answering :) it helps